# Simple Json in PHP

Tags: php, json, load, decode, file-get-contents

I have a simple task that does not work 
I Have a json file..

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: why do I get ths error

argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dynamiskweb\Webservices\WEBSERVICES-02.php on line 38

Comment: what error do you get? I don't see any error in your question

Comment: argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dynamiskweb\Webservices\WEBSERVICES-02.php on line 38

Comment: first of all, include the error in the question, because like this, that is not a question... second, `var_dump($content)` and see what it contains

Comment: I'm sorry that the quastion is not easy to understand .. it's because this is my first time using this website

Comment: no problem :) if you don't know, we can teach you :) it's ok

Comment: website isn't the problem. you didn't ask the question in the 1st place.... what you want? what you got? if error occured what is the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you decode with the 'true' bool as second param, you will get an associative array back.   In your code snippet you then loop it out.
What you should do, is skip the loop and just access the data from the assoc array right away:

```
echo $array['navn'];


// The JSON object:
{"nr":"5250","navn":"Odense SV","adresser":"http://oiorest.dk/danmark/postdistrikter/5250/adresser"}
// Is equivalent to this php assoc-array:
array("nr" => "5250", "navn" => "Odense SV", "adresser" => "http://oiorest.dk/danmark/postdistrikter/5250/adresser");
```

Comment: Happy to help. If it was the correct answer, please mark it as correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
<?php
$url = "http://oiorest.dk/danmark/postdistrikter/5000.json";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$array = json_decode($content, true);
foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {
    echo $val;

}
?>
```

Comment: actually, @Jite 's answer is better, I think

Comment: Im kinda confused with this solution, all it does is loop through the object as many times as there is key-value pairs and `print_r` the `navn` value. Why use the loop? :P

Comment: if you getting multiple value then loop require otherwise fine without loop

Comment: Wouldnt each loop then be: `print_r($array[$key]);` or rather just: `echo $val;`?